# Version number of Windows 7 from its image (iso,..)

Tags: windows-7, version

How find out version number of Windows 7 from its DVD image before installing it?

Comment: Version number? Do you mean architecture (32-bit/64-bit), service pack (RTM/SP1), edition (Starter/Home Basic/Home Premium/Professional/Enterprise/Ultimate) or the *version number*, as in build number (note Windows 7 is always 6.1, with varying build numbers depending on service pack)?

Comment: @Bob All of them. In particular build number

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming you can mount the image, run cmd as administrator and type:

```
dism /Get-WimInfo /WimFile:A:\sources\boot.wim
```

**A** is your iso mountpoint.

or just extract the `boot.wim` file to somewhere and use its location in the command above.

Update: If you open **boot.wim**, there is an xml file usually called `[1].xml`. in there you can find the exact build information similar to this:

```
<WINDOWS>
<ARCH>0</ARCH>
<PRODUCTNAME>Microsoft® Windows® Operating System</PRODUCTNAME>
<EDITIONID>WindowsPE</EDITIONID>
<INSTALLATIONTYPE>WindowsPE</INSTALLATIONTYPE>
<PRODUCTTYPE>WinNT</PRODUCTTYPE>
<PRODUCTSUITE/><LANGUAGES>
<LANGUAGE>en-US</LANGUAGE>
<DEFAULT>en-US</DEFAULT></LANGUAGES>
<VERSION><MAJOR>6</MAJOR><MINOR>1</MINOR><BUILD>7601</BUILD><SPBUILD>17514</SPBUILD><SPLEVEL>1</SPLEVEL></VERSION><SYSTEMROOT>WINDOWS</SYSTEMROOT></WINDOWS>
```

The `<version>` tag is what tells you the built version. for above example: V 6.1.7601 SP1.17514

Comment: This shows the architecture. However, it does not show the build number, service pack level or edition when I attempted it on my Windows 7 DVD. Depending on what @Reza meant by *version number*, this may or may not answer the question (and if architecture was meant, then this is a duplicate question).

Comment: Read the update please.

Comment: Nice! However, it would be better if you could describe how to *open* `boot.wim`. So far, I've attempted to mount it with `dism`, which does not reveal a `[1].xml` anywhere.

Comment: I used 7-zip, but there are several alternatives.

Comment: Ah, you extracted the image itself rather than mounting it... To clarify for others, `[1].xml` is actually metadata of the `boot.wim` image that you can see if you extract it with something like 7-Zip, but not if you mount it with something like `dism` (and maybe `ImageX`).

Comment: Yes Bob you are correct. thanks for clarifying it.

Comment: How can I find the available windows edition of an ISO file (Home, Ultimate, ...)

Answer (score 3):

Nima is onto something, however newer images can have multiple indexes, so you get more details by adding /index:1 or equivalent. See here for a Windows 8 example (from cmd as Administrator):

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>dism /Get-WimInfo /WimFile:D:\sources\boot.wim

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.3.9600.16384

Details for image : D:\sources\boot.wim

Index : 1
Name : Microsoft Windows PE (x64)
Description : Microsoft Windows PE (x64)
Size : 1,187,717,206 bytes

Index : 2
Name : Microsoft Windows Setup (x64)
Description : Microsoft Windows Setup (x64)
Size : 1,264,587,270 bytes

The operation completed successfully.
```

Windows PE is the installation environment, so I guess here we really want to look at index 2 instead.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>dism /Get-WimInfo /WimFile:D:\sources\boot.wim /index:2

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.3.9600.16384

Details for image : D:\sources\boot.wim

Index : 2
Name : Microsoft Windows Setup (x64)
Description : Microsoft Windows Setup (x64)
Size : 1,264,587,270 bytes
Architecture : x64
Hal : 
Version : 6.2.9200
ServicePack Build : 16384
ServicePack Level : 0
Edition : WindowsPE
Installation : WindowsPE
ProductType : WinNT
ProductSuite :
System Root : WINDOWS
Directories : 2977
Files : 13452
Created : 2012-07-26 - 07:40:09
Modified : 2012-07-26 - 09:04:49
Languages :
        en-US (Default)

The operation completed successfully.
```

Answer (score 2):

All those answers are good except that you can simply open the ISO with 7-Zip and in the "sources" folder open, inside of 7-Zip, the file "install.wim". In the XML file mentioned, when opened, you will find exactly what "SPLEVEL" you have regardless of what the OS "NAME" is. No need to open "boot.wim" or mount it for that matter.

Cheers