# Verify Windows 10 Anniversary update ISO

Tags: windows, windows-10, security, windows-10-v1607

I used the Media Creation Tool to create an ISO of the Windows 10 Anniversary update (or so I hope).

Is there any way of verifying the Windows version of the ISO?

Comment: May be this is what you're looking for? [How to determine the version of your Windows ISO file](http://www.waynezim.com/2012/10/how-to-determine-the-version-of-your-windows-iso-file/)

Comment: What is the name of the iso file ? Is there something like 14393 or 1607 in that file name ?

Comment: @CodeIt `Windows.iso`.

Comment: @w32sh I need to check that out.

Comment: @w32sh should be an answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Version number of Windows 7 from its image (iso,..)](http://superuser.com/questions/443357/version-number-of-windows-7-from-its-image-iso)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mount the ISO and note down the drive-letter. Let's say it's `E:\`

Right-click Start, click `Command Prompt (Admin)`

Type the following command and hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

```
dism /Get-WimInfo /WimFile:E:\sources\install.wim /index:1
```

In case you don't have the install.wim file (you may have `install.esd` you used the Media Creation Tool), use this command:

```
dism /Get-WimInfo /WimFile:E:\sources\boot.wim /index:1
```

You can see the Version number there.

**Credits:** [How to determine the version of your Windows ISO file | Wayne Zimmerman's Blog](http://www.waynezim.com/2012/10/how-to-determine-the-version-of-your-windows-iso-file/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to verify your ISO, however, if you know your version and Edition of Windows then you can check the build number as stated in this [article](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wiki/windows_10-windows_install/how-to-download-official-windows-10-iso-files/35cde7ec-5b6f-481c-a02d-dadf465df326). Then you can be sure that you have the official version. Please let me know if you need help regarding your build number.

Thank you.